# Does snowflake support ssl?

Tags: ssl, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I want to have the ability to connect from jdbc driver to snowflake with ssl. I did it many times with other db, just add ssl=true(sometimes other properties) in connection url.

Unfortunately I didn't find this option in snowflake documentation. I found that snowflake supports something like ssl they call it [Using Key Pair Authentication](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#using-key-pair-authentication)
Does it ssl mode for snowflake? 
Does snowflake support ssl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a jdbc connection property `ssl` to `on` or `off` as seen [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/net/snowflake/client/jdbc/ConnectionIT.java#L283)

That's what determines if the connection will be made via https or http, going by the implementation [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/core/HttpUtil.java#L281)

I tried it and it worked for me.

Note that if `ssl` is not set, the value is `on` by default.

Comment: is it a 2 way ssl?

Answer (score 4):

I believe Snowflake *only* allows HTTPS to connect, and so it always uses TLS/SSL.

Comment: @ИванГладуш You should be setting the `SSL` connection property to `on`, that's when the connection will be made via Https.

Comment: @KehindeAdedamolaShittu Do you what say that Snowflake can work without ssl?

Comment: @ИванГладуш After looking closely at the implementation here https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/jdbc/SnowflakeConnectionV1.java#L188-L194, I realize :
1. SSL for snowflake can be turned on and off by setting connection parameter `ssl`
2. The `ssl` conn param is `on` by default, so it's not necessary to set it explicitly. but it can be turned `off` and snowflake will connect via HTTP.  
So my point is, Snowflake allows HTTP connection if `ssl` is set to off.

Comment: @Marcin Zukowski is it true?

Comment: Yes I think in theory it's possible to disable ssl, but it's only used for internal testing - I don't think you can connect to a Snowflake deployment without SSL enabled.

Answer (score 3):

SSL encryption cannot be switched off when connecting to Snowflake. Full Stop.

There is no option in the `JDBC` or `ODBC` driver to disable (or enable) SSL. That is why this parameter is not mentioned on the documentation pages of Snowflake.

- [Generic](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html)
- [ODBC](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#configuration-parameters)

Snowflake connections use SSL by default.

And using only HTTPS connections. Regardless whether it is a driver or the GUI.

That is also the reason that you do not need to add `https://` to your server connection.

More on this can be found [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-encryption.html).

The http-connections you might see Snowflake drivers make are to satisfy OCSP.

If you trying to test whether Snowflake supports un-encrypted connections and you get the information back that Snowflake does support unencrypted connections or does support **TLS1.0** or **TLS1.1** you have been testing your proxy-server settings and not snowflakecomputing.com or snowflake.com.

BTW : Currently only **TLS1.2** is supported by Snowflake for **HTTPS** connections.