# Does snowflake support ssl using ODBC?

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to connect to Snowflake using ODBC, and I saw that it is SSL enabled by default([Does snowflake support ssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55161683/does-snowflake-support-ssl)).
Appreciate where I can have it formally from Snowflake, as I yet to find as such documentation..

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All snowflake connectivity is to:

https://..snowflakecomputing.com

Even the ODBC connector is just a wrapper for HTTPS calls to then https URL above.  That means that everything in snowflake, Web UI, JDBC, ODBC, snowsql, Python etc all runs over HTTPS and SSL.

It's also worth noting to meet the security standards here, all traffic must be SSL:

https://www.snowflake.com/snowflakes-security-compliance-reports/

Answer (score 1):

> Appreciate where I can have it formally from Snowflake

The Snowflake Security Policy specifies that all customer data in transit is encrypted with TLS 1.2.

https://www.snowflake.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/2018July12-Snowflake-Security-Policy.pdf

Reference section 3.1. Encryption of Customer Data, which states "Snowflake leverages Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.2 (or better) for Customer Data in-transit over untrusted networks."

This statement applies to all customer data in transit, so ODBC is included.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the following document, which has a bunch of different sections that reference SSL, OCSP, and openSSL key-pair settings.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html

Comment: Hi Mike,

I read this one, and still cannot find where it is mentioned that SSL is default using ODBC connection.

Comment: Does the reference to the default port being 443 help?  Or the reference to OCSP being standard, which validates the SSL certificate?  I did misread your initial request, but the documentation still has many references to the default behavior with SSL.