# What protocol does SnowFlake JDBC driver use?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to find out what protocol the [SnowFlake JDBC library](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc.html) uses to communicate with SnowFlake. I see hints here and there that it seems to be using HTTPS as the protocol. Is this true?

To my knowledge, other JDBC libraries like for example for Oracle or PostgreSQL use the lower level TCP protocol to communicate with their database servers, and not the application-level HTTP(S) protocol, so I'm confused.

My organization only supports securely routing http(s)-based communication. Can I use this snowflake jdbc library then?
I have browsed all documentation that I could find, but wasn't able to answer this question.
My [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/issues/1232) didn't get an answer either.

Edit: Yes, I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55161683/1446479), but I don't feel that it answers my question. SSL/TLS is an encryption, but that doesn't specify the data format.

Comment: TCP is a transport layer protocol, so you still need something on top of that to transfer the application data. In case of Snowflake it is TLS. All data transfer between the driver (all Snowflake drivers actually) and Snowflake is encrypted using TLS.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the jdbc driver uses HTTP Client `HttpUtil.initHttpClient(httpClientSettingsKey, null);`, as you can see in [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/core/SFSession.java#L475)

The `HTTP Utility Class` is available [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/core/HttpUtil.java)

Putting an excerpt of the session open method here in case the link goes bad/dead.

```
  /**
   * Open a new database session
   *
   * @throws SFException this is a runtime exception
   * @throws SnowflakeSQLException exception raised from Snowflake components
   */
  public synchronized void open() throws SFException, SnowflakeSQLException {
    performSanityCheckOnProperties();
    Map<SFSessionProperty, Object> connectionPropertiesMap = getConnectionPropertiesMap();
    logger.debug(
        "input: server={}, account={}, user={}, password={}, role={}, database={}, schema={},"
            + " warehouse={}, validate_default_parameters={}, authenticator={}, ocsp_mode={},"
            + " passcode_in_password={}, passcode={}, private_key={}, disable_socks_proxy={},"
            + " application={}, app_id={}, app_version={}, login_timeout={}, network_timeout={},"
            + " query_timeout={}, tracing={}, private_key_file={}, private_key_file_pwd={}."
            + " session_parameters: client_store_temporary_credential={}",
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.SERVER_URL),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.ACCOUNT),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.USER),
        !Strings.isNullOrEmpty((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.PASSWORD))
            ? "***"
            : "(empty)",
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.ROLE),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.DATABASE),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.SCHEMA),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.WAREHOUSE),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.VALIDATE_DEFAULT_PARAMETERS),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.AUTHENTICATOR),
        getOCSPMode().name(),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.PASSCODE_IN_PASSWORD),
        !Strings.isNullOrEmpty((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.PASSCODE))
            ? "***"
            : "(empty)",
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.PRIVATE_KEY) != null
            ? "(not null)"
            : "(null)",
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.DISABLE_SOCKS_PROXY),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.APPLICATION),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.APP_ID),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.APP_VERSION),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.LOGIN_TIMEOUT),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.NETWORK_TIMEOUT),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.QUERY_TIMEOUT),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.TRACING),
        connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE),
        !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(
                (String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PWD))
            ? "***"
            : "(empty)",
        sessionParametersMap.get(CLIENT_STORE_TEMPORARY_CREDENTIAL));

    HttpClientSettingsKey httpClientSettingsKey = getHttpClientKey();
    logger.debug(
        "connection proxy parameters: use_proxy={}, proxy_host={}, proxy_port={}, proxy_user={},"
            + " proxy_password={}, non_proxy_hosts={}, proxy_protocol={}",
        httpClientSettingsKey.usesProxy(),
        httpClientSettingsKey.getProxyHost(),
        httpClientSettingsKey.getProxyPort(),
        httpClientSettingsKey.getProxyUser(),
        !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(httpClientSettingsKey.getProxyPassword()) ? "***" : "(empty)",
        httpClientSettingsKey.getNonProxyHosts(),
        httpClientSettingsKey.getProxyProtocol());

    // TODO: temporarily hardcode sessionParameter debug info. will be changed in the future
    SFLoginInput loginInput = new SFLoginInput();

    loginInput
        .setServerUrl((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.SERVER_URL))
        .setDatabaseName((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.DATABASE))
        .setSchemaName((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.SCHEMA))
        .setWarehouse((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.WAREHOUSE))
        .setRole((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.ROLE))
        .setValidateDefaultParameters(
            connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.VALIDATE_DEFAULT_PARAMETERS))
        .setAuthenticator((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.AUTHENTICATOR))
        .setOKTAUserName((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.OKTA_USERNAME))
        .setAccountName((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.ACCOUNT))
        .setLoginTimeout(loginTimeout)
        .setAuthTimeout(authTimeout)
        .setUserName((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.USER))
        .setPassword((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.PASSWORD))
        .setToken((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.TOKEN))
        .setPasscodeInPassword(passcodeInPassword)
        .setPasscode((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.PASSCODE))
        .setConnectionTimeout(httpClientConnectionTimeout)
        .setSocketTimeout(httpClientSocketTimeout)
        .setAppId((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.APP_ID))
        .setAppVersion((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.APP_VERSION))
        .setSessionParameters(sessionParametersMap)
        .setPrivateKey((PrivateKey) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.PRIVATE_KEY))
        .setPrivateKeyFile((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE))
        .setPrivateKeyFilePwd(
            (String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PWD))
        .setApplication((String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.APPLICATION))
        .setServiceName(getServiceName())
        .setOCSPMode(getOCSPMode())
        .setHttpClientSettingsKey(httpClientSettingsKey);

    // propagate OCSP mode to SFTrustManager. Note OCSP setting is global on JVM.
    HttpUtil.initHttpClient(httpClientSettingsKey, null);
    SFLoginOutput loginOutput =
        SessionUtil.openSession(loginInput, connectionPropertiesMap, tracingLevel.toString());
    isClosed = false;

    authTimeout = loginInput.getAuthTimeout();
    sessionToken = loginOutput.getSessionToken();
    masterToken = loginOutput.getMasterToken();
    idToken = loginOutput.getIdToken();
    mfaToken = loginOutput.getMfaToken();
    setDatabaseVersion(loginOutput.getDatabaseVersion());
    setDatabaseMajorVersion(loginOutput.getDatabaseMajorVersion());
    setDatabaseMinorVersion(loginOutput.getDatabaseMinorVersion());
    httpClientSocketTimeout = loginOutput.getHttpClientSocketTimeout();
    masterTokenValidityInSeconds = loginOutput.getMasterTokenValidityInSeconds();
    setDatabase(loginOutput.getSessionDatabase());
    setSchema(loginOutput.getSessionSchema());
    setRole(loginOutput.getSessionRole());
    setWarehouse(loginOutput.getSessionWarehouse());
    setSessionId(loginOutput.getSessionId());
    setAutoCommit(loginOutput.getAutoCommit());

    // Update common parameter values for this session
    SessionUtil.updateSfDriverParamValues(loginOutput.getCommonParams(), this);

    String loginDatabaseName = (String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.DATABASE);
    String loginSchemaName = (String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.SCHEMA);
    String loginRole = (String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.ROLE);
    String loginWarehouse = (String) connectionPropertiesMap.get(SFSessionProperty.WAREHOUSE);

    if (loginDatabaseName != null && !loginDatabaseName.equalsIgnoreCase(getDatabase())) {
      sqlWarnings.add(
          new SFException(
              ErrorCode.CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED_WITH_DIFFERENT_PROP,
              "Database",
              loginDatabaseName,
              getDatabase()));
    }

    if (loginSchemaName != null && !loginSchemaName.equalsIgnoreCase(getSchema())) {
      sqlWarnings.add(
          new SFException(
              ErrorCode.CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED_WITH_DIFFERENT_PROP,
              "Schema",
              loginSchemaName,
              getSchema()));
    }

    if (loginRole != null && !loginRole.equalsIgnoreCase(getRole())) {
      sqlWarnings.add(
          new SFException(
              ErrorCode.CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED_WITH_DIFFERENT_PROP, "Role", loginRole, getRole()));
    }

    if (loginWarehouse != null && !loginWarehouse.equalsIgnoreCase(getWarehouse())) {
      sqlWarnings.add(
          new SFException(
              ErrorCode.CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED_WITH_DIFFERENT_PROP,
              "Warehouse",
              loginWarehouse,
              getWarehouse()));
    }

    // start heartbeat for this session so that the master token will not expire
    startHeartbeatForThisSession();
  }
```